# Banshee under Unity stops playing music when hitting the (x) icon

Tags: 11.04, banshee

When running Banshee under Unity on Natty (upgraded from Maverick), music plays as expected but when hitting the (x) button on the title bar the window exits and the music stops as well.

Answer (score 3):

When upgrading the banshee extension providing soundmenu integration was not automatically enabled.  Enabling this extension allows banshee to show itself in the soundmenu indicator and also to close its window without stopping playback.

To change this option open the preferences dialog box (Edit/Preferences on the menu), and select the Extensions tab.  Use the search box to find "sound menu" and ensure that the tick box on the right is selected.

Comment: +1 Note: in contrast to my solution, this will quit Banshee only if not playing music. Anyways, the sound menu extension wasn't enabled on my fresh Natty installation, so this doesn't seem to be default.

Answer (score 1):

That's the intended behavior.

However, you can install the `banshee-extension-appindicator` package and enable the *Application Indicator for Banshee* via *Edit → Preferences → Extension*. This will prevent Banshee from quitting when closing its window.